# Background thread does not stop when foreground thread stop?

Tags: c#, multithreading

When I'am running the example provided in the following link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.isbackground?view=netframework-4.8

```
class Example
{
    static void Main()
    {
        BackgroundTest shortTest = new BackgroundTest(10);
        Thread foregroundThread = 
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(shortTest.RunLoop));

        BackgroundTest longTest = new BackgroundTest(50);
        Thread backgroundThread = 
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(longTest.RunLoop));
        backgroundThread.IsBackground = true;

        foregroundThread.Start();
        backgroundThread.Start();
    }
}
```

according to the documentation,the background thread should stop when the foreground thread stops.I run this example on my computer and the background thread does not stop and continues to print the numbers in the for loop.Also,the number ten is printed only once, not twice as in the example , as the for loop is running from 0 to 9.This is the output that I receive from the example,without making any modifications to the example:

https://pastebin.com/AsfEX6gf

Is it the documentation wrong or it depends on the CPU architecture ?

Comment: What about inserting this line "the foregroundThread.IsBackground = false"  before long test definition. does it change the output?

Comment: I does not change the output,but what I observed while testing your idea is that if I insert Console.Readline() after  backgroundThread.Start(); the program continues to print the numbers.If I do not add it,the program does stop after it prints the number 9.Why is this happening ?

Comment: @WorkoutChannel Console.Readline() blocks your main thread untill you provide the input and since your main thread is a foreground thread - your background thread keeps on counting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried it with diferent CLR's and I used both .Net Framework and .Net Core - works as it should work.
But as mentioned in the comments section if you put `Console.Readline()` at the end of your Main function - it blocks your main thread until you provide an input and since your main thread is a foreground thread - the background thread keeps on counting.